# List of -D properties from ant command line

Tags: command-line, ant, properties

I have process that runs multiple jobs with varying -D properties being passed in. Is there a way to get a list of the -D properties that was passed on the ant command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all properties specified on the command line as

```
<propertyset id="commandline-properties">
  <propertyref builtin="commandline"/>
</propertyset>
```

and use `<echoproperties>` to show them. The `propertyset` will also contain some special Ant properties related to the command line - the build file in `ant.file`, the type of build file in `ant.file.type` and the targets invoked from the command line in `ant.project.invoked-targets`. For example

```
$ cat < props.xml 
<project>
  <echoproperties>
    <propertyset>
      <propertyref builtin="commandline"/>
    </propertyset>
  </echoproperties>
</project>
$ ant -f props.xml -Dfoo=bar -Dxyzzy=quoox
Buildfile: /tmp/props.xml
[echoproperties] #Ant properties
[echoproperties] #Fri Sep 16 22:21:51 CEST 2016
[echoproperties] ant.file=/tmp/props.xml
[echoproperties] ant.file.type=file
[echoproperties] ant.project.invoked-targets=
[echoproperties] foo=bar
[echoproperties] xyzzy=quoox

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```